# Wireless headphones (USB Dongle/Bluetooth) are detected but no sound

Tags: sound, headphones, logitech

I have a problem with my wireless headphones that can be connected via USB Dongle & Bluetooth (Logitech G435).

So the problem is that the system (Ubuntu 22.04) detects my headphones, I can see them in Input/Output section, I can even hear sound in headphones when I click "Test" button, however when it comes to sound in any other app (browser, notifications, skype, music, etc.) - the sound is played via my laptop speakers. The same behavior is with Bluetooth connection.

I can make it work by using `pavucontrol` tool by manual disabling speakers ([here is a screenshot of pavucontrol configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba0pc.png)). In this case headphones work fine, but I'd like to configure it properly without doing any manual actions each time when I'm turning on my headphones.

My investigations:

1. This issue appears only on this headphones. I've tried several other headphones and they work fine (USB/Minijack/Bluetooth connections).
2. This issue appears only on Ubuntu. On the same laptop but on Windows everything works perfectly. I've also tried a PS5 console & MacBook - everything is good.

Could you please help me with resolving this issue?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The product has a bunch of bad reviews. Its early lot has buggy firmware. 1) Update firmware 2) Ask Logitech to fix the problem